# Android: How to set the name of the compiled APK?

Tags: android

This question seems embarassingly simple, yet it vexes me still. I am using the standard ADT and Eclipse Android environment to build my Android app. The apk is named after the project name in Eclipse, but I want to name the apk something different...How can I customize the name of the apk artifact that is produced when the project builds?

Comment: You rename it? Or change the name of your project?

Comment: I prefer not to change the name of my project, as I have another project already with the same name I want for the APK. And, I prefer not to rename it by hand because that seems like a bad hack and might be problematic when signing the file and zipaligning it in Eclipse.

Answer (score 9):

android update project --name **your_desired_name** --path .

ant debug

Comment: that's just great... I used `android update project --path .` to generate a `build.xml` file; never thought it would mess things up not specifying a name :/

Comment: Note that this will overwrite you custom build.xml in case you have one.

Answer (score 5):

You can also just edit the build.xml as following:

```
<project name="YourNewProjectNameHere" ...
```

if you are building with "ant" on the command line. Otherwise, Eclipse will always use your official ProjectName when create an apk. However, you can override that by right-clicking on project, and selecting Android Tools->Export Signed Application Package; which will then allow you to specify your own name for the package.

Answer (score 1):

I am very surprised that there apparently is no way to do this, but alas I found that when finally exporting a signed apk file through eclipse you can specify the name of the APK. So that solves my problem.

Comment: In the last step, it gives you a path to the file it will save when you click Finish. You can open a normal save dialog there.

Answer (score 0):

**Please Try This...**

**Please First Change \android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml for signed release apk**

**These changes are onetime in build.xml because of  this file every time use with your project build.xml to generate apk**

```
<property name="out.final.file" location="${out.absolute.dir}/${ant.project.name}-release.apk" />
```

**By**

```
<property name="out.final.file" location="${out.absolute.dir}/${ant.project.name}.apk" />
```

Then execute command : 

**android update project --name your_desired_name --path .**

**ant release**


**Release APK Created in directory YourProjectName\bin by name :**

your_desired_name.apk

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to change the apk's name that appears on the smartphone's screen, you just need to go to click **your project > res > values > string.xml** then on app_name field inside the **><** renamed the apk's name as you want.

[image]