# android : app name when installing APK

Tags: android

Am working on an Android App & have recently changed the App's name. I changed it in AndroidManifest.xml in 
    
I then built the signed APK & opened the APK for installation on an android device. I opened using 'Package installer'. Then it shows a screen with the App name & shows the list of permissions that the App asks for. In this screen, am still seeing the old name. How do I change it? Can someone please help?

Comment: This may help 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5443304/how-to-change-an-android-apps-name

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your "android:label" attribute

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/title"
    android:label="MY NEW APP NAME" >
```

in your AndroidManifest.xml

I also found this asked and answered [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6777813/how-to-change-apk-name-by-editing-manifest-file)