# APK name doesn't change in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm with a problem on Android Studio. I created an app but when I compiled and putting on my device, the app name not change. My app name is eCoding but appears FolioReader.
I already change AndroidManifest and Strings, but doesn't work. Someone help me?

[image: Screenshot]

[AndroidManifest and Strings](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ixOEWABUC3KtTdYLn1_HWzVZBayz_iWD/view?usp=sharing)

Here is my `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.app.eCoding">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> <!-- for card.io card scanning -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
    android:required="false" />

<application
    android:name="com.app.eCoding.Utility.MyApp"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
    android:resizeableActivity="false"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">

    <uses-library
        android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
        android:required="false" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" /> <!-- TODO: Replace with your real AdMob app ID -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="@string/admob_main_id" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme"
                tools:ignore="ManifestResource" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.app.eCoding.Activity.SplashActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.app.eCoding.Activity.Privacypolicy"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.app.eCoding.Activity.AllPaymentActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.app.eCoding.Activity.DownloadedBooks"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.app.eCoding.Activity.Paidbookallview"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.app.eCoding.Activity.FreeBookallview"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.app.eCoding.Activity.WelcomeActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.app.eCoding.Activity.LoginActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.app.eCoding.Activity.Registration"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.app.eCoding.Activity.MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.app.eCoding.Activity.BookDetails"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.app.eCoding.Activity.PDFShow"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        tools:ignore="DuplicateActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.app.eCoding.Activity.PermissionActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.app.eCoding.Activity.AuthorBookList"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.app.eCoding.Activity.CategoryBookList"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.app.eCoding.Activity.NewArrivalAll"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.app.eCoding.Activity.CategoryViewAll"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.app.eCoding.Activity.FeatureItemsViewAll"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.app.eCoding.Activity.AuthorAllActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.app.eCoding.Activity.MyDownloadBooks"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.app.eCoding.Activity.Profile"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.app.eCoding.Activity.AboutUs"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.folioreader.ui.folio.activity.FolioActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />

    <service
        android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalService"
        android:exported="false" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.razorpay.ApiKey"
        android:value="rzp_test_AKowaIwN4V6A9W" />

    <activity android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentActivity" />
    <activity android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.LoginActivity" />
    <activity android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentMethodActivity" />
    <activity android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentConfirmActivity" />
    <activity android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalFuturePaymentActivity" />
    <activity android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.FuturePaymentConsentActivity" />
    <activity android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.FuturePaymentInfoActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name="io.card.payment.CardIOActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" />
    <activity android:name="io.card.payment.DataEntryActivity" />
</application>
```

and this is my `strings.xml`

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<string name="app_name">eCoding</string>

<string name="next">NEXT</string>
<string name="skip">SKIP</string>
<string name="start">GOT IT</string>


<!--Facebook-->
<string name="facebook_app_id" tools:ignore="MissingTranslation">6140</string>
<string name="fb_login_protocol_scheme" tools:ignore="MissingTranslation">fb66</string>

<!--Gmail-->
<string name="web_client_id" tools:ignore="MissingTranslation">47662tdm.apps.googleusercontent.com</string>
<string name="Secrate" tools:ignore="MissingTranslation">qZAUC</string>


<!--Login-->

<string name="email">Email Address</string>
<string name="email_hint">Email</string>
<string name="password">Password</string>
<string name="remember">Remember Me</string>

<string name="login">Login</string>
<string name="skip1">Skip</string>
<string name="dont">Don\'t have an account ?</string>
<string name="signup"> Signup</string>
<string name="logout"> logout</string>

<!--End Login-->

<!--Registration-->

<string name="full_name">Full Name</string>
<string name="phone">Phone</string>
<string name="signup_cap">SIGN UP</string>
<string name="already_account">Already have an account Yet?</string>

<!--End Registration-->

<!--About Us-->

<string name="Company">Company</string>
<string name="website">Website</string>
<string name="Contact">Contact</string>

<!--End About Us-->

<!--Home-->

<string name="Category">Category</string>
<string name="Categories">Categories</string>
<string name="View_all">View All</string>


<string name="Top_Reading_Book">Top Reading Book</string>
<string name="New_Arrival_Book">New Arrival Book</string>
<string name="Authors">Authors</string>
<string name="Free_Book">Free Book</string>
<string name="Paid_Book">Paid Book</string>
<string name="Continue_Reading">Continue Reading</string>

<!--End Home-->

<!--Search-->

<string name="Search">Search</string>
<string name="See_All">See All</string>
<string name="Payment">Payment</string>
<string name="Please_select_any_payment_method">Please select any payment method</string>
<string name="CONTINUE">CONTINUE</string>
<string name="Books">Books</string>

<string name="Reviews">Reviews</string>
<string name="Downloads">Downloads</string>
<string name="Book_Details">Book Details</string>
<string name="What_is_this_book_about">What is this book about ?</string>

<string name="Related_Books">Related Books</string>
<string name="Comments">Comments</string>
<string name="Write_your_comments">Write your comments</string>

<string name="My_Purchase_Books">My Purchase Books</string>
<string name="ALLOW_PERMISSION">ALLOW PERMISSION</string>

<string name="wel_one">Book Details</string>
<string name="wel_two">Reviews</string>
<string name="wel_three">Downloads</string>
<string name="wel_four">Downloads</string>

<!--End Search-->

<string name="title_home">Home</string>
<string name="title_search">Search</string>
<string name="title_bookmark">Bookmark</string>
<string name="title_Premium">Premium</string>
<string name="title_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="isRTL">false</string>
<string name="internet_connection">Internet connection not available</string>

<string name="permission_desc">Now we need your permission to continue use the application perfectly</string>
<string name="permission_title">Everything is okey</string>


<string name="profile">Profile</string>
<string name="save">save</string>

<string name="my_Purchase_book">My Purchase Books</string>
<string name="my_downloaded_book">My Downloaded Books</string>
<string name="enable_push_notification">Enable push notification</string>
<string name="enable_theme">Enable Day/Night mode</string>
<string name="clear_cache">Clear Cache</string>
<string name="locally_cached_data">locally cached data</string>
<string name="Privacy_policy">Privacy policy</string>

<string name="rate_app">Rate App</string>
<string name="share_app">Share App</string>
<string name="about_us">About Us</string>
<string name="downloading">Downloading</string>

<string name="change_language">Language</string>
```

Comment: Don't post screenshots of text. Put the actual text (properly formatted) directly into your question.

Comment: Sorry, I’m newbie

Comment: android:name="com.app.eCoding.Utility.MyApp"
remove that line and try again.

Comment: Are you sure you use the right strings-file? maybe you're only editing a translation? Also, use translatable="false" so you don't need tools:ignore="MissingTranslation"

Comment: this may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5443324/8192914

Comment: can you let me know if adding `android:label="@string/app_name"` below `android:name="com.app.eCoding.Activity.MainActivity"` works?

Comment: @ahmad bajwa doesn’t work 

Comment: @m.reiter yeah, exist 4 strings (French, English and Arabic) and Strings.xml common

Comment: @ganjaam doesn’t work 

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change apk name by editing manifest file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6777813/how-to-change-apk-name-by-editing-manifest-file)

Comment: @Morpheus not quite, I want to change the name of the App on my device :(

Comment: Have you tried invalidating caches and restarting Android Studio?

Comment: @m.reiter I did it now, I even reinstalled android studio .. but to no avail

Answer (score 0):

[image: screenshot 1]

in manifest change to -> android:label="@string/app_name"
and change app_name in strings

[image: screenshot 2]

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your Manifest:

[image: Try this in your Manifest:]

```
    android:label="YourAppName"
```

Comment: only compiles if I use @ strings / app_name anyway it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Your settings look good. However, I noticed that the tags are not closed properly.

```
<manifest> in AndroidManifest.xml (requires </manifest> at the end of file)
<resources> in strings.xml (requires </resources> at the end of file)
```

Comment: I do not see the "xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" in <resources> tag.in my running project. Please remove.